# Edit a service created on Centos

Tags: centos, services

I am trying to debug a service created on a unix server that I was told should be running and will just require a restart when there is an issue by using the following command:

```
service controller-watchdog start
```

But when trying this, the response was 'couldn't find controller-watchdog'. I found this weird and then searched the folder etc/init.d and see it listed there. Also when using the following command

```
service --status-all
```

the same response appears. Why would it even list this response if the service does not exist. I am not very familiar with unix so please advise how I can edit the script that was created for this service if I don't know what the name is. Thanks.

EDIT:

Could someone please guide me that for any service running, where would I find the scripts created for these?

Comment: What version of CentOS are you running?

Comment: Centos 6.9 version

Comment: Add the output of `chkconfig --list | grep control` to your question

Comment: no result is returned

Comment: Figured it out and found the service